GitLab Terraform Registry: Unable to download a specific module from a nested directory structure
I have directory structure for my terraform project as below and i am trying to push this directory structure to gitlab terraform module registry.
stack
 - vpc
 - db
 - dns


As per the Gitlab dicumentation i can download the terraform module like this.
module "my_module_name" {
  source = "gitlab.com/xfinity/stack/local"
  version = "1.0.0"
}

To authorize access to the Terraform registry:
credentials "gitlab.com" {
  token = "<TOKEN>"
}


What i want to do is something like this.
module "my_module_name" {
  source = "gitlab.com/xfinity/stack/local//vpc?ref=1.0.0"
}

But the problem i am facing is since my directory structure is nested, i am not able to reference a particular module like vpc or db in my source configuration.
I am unable to use Git or HTTPS source URLs to download a Terraform module from the GitLab registry because authentication with an SSH key is enforced when using an SSH URL. I prefer to use a Personal Access Token (PAT) for authentication instead.
Can you please suggest me how can i achieve this, without using a ssh or https source?

Download it to your filesystem and reference its location relative to wherever you're keeping the Terraform code.

can you please elaborate on this a little bit more? How can i reference its location?

Have you tried accessing the module via the git source instead of referencing GitLab's Terraform registry? Something like this:
module "my_module_name" {
  source = "git::https://gitlab.com/xfinity/stack/local//vpc?ref=1.0.0"
  version = "1.0.0"
}

The docs on GitLab do not mention the usage of submodules so it may be a limitation from their side. Bear in mind that the authentication process may be different than the one you're currently using.
